# Differ in signedness - warning

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, socklen-t

I don't understand my warning in gcc compiler.
Warning is: `warning: pointer targets in passing argument 6 of ‘recvfrom’ differ in signedness` I don't know, where is a problem, I am not using `signed and unsigned` value.

Problem is on line:

```
recvfrom(server_socket, inputbuffer, maxLenght, 0, (struct sockaddr*) remote_addr, &server_addr_len);
```

I tried this:

```
recvfrom(server_socket, inputbuffer, maxLenght, 0, (unsigned int) remote_addr, &server_addr_len);
```

But it didn't help me. Thank you for your advice and explanation.

Comment: which one is the 6th argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [man `recvfrom()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html):

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                    struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

`recvfrom()` expects a `socklen_t` as 6th parameter. You probably pass an `int`.

So define `server_addr_len` like so:

```
socklen_t server_addr_len;
```

Comment: `socklen_t server_addr_len;` is both declaration **and** definition. `extern socklen_t server_addr_len;` would be a declaration only. `socklen_t server_addr_len = 0;` is declaration **and** definition **and** initialisation. @iharob For your reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration

Comment: Thank you sir for proving the link. One question though, is there anything to do with the storage class? I mean to say, can I phrase like this "_in case of `auto` storage, `socklen_t server_addr_len;` is always a valid definition, however, for `extern`, this might not be always the case_", keeping in mind, `-fno-common` is missing at compile time?

Comment: A "declaration" is a promise, a "definition" is a fact. @SouravGhosh

Answer (score 2):

See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) of `recvfrom()`.

It says, the function prototype is

```
 ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
             struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

The 6th argument is `socklen_t *addrlen`. So, while calling `recvfrom()` from your application, you have to use it like

```
socklen_t server_addr_len = 0;
struct sockaddr * remote_addr = NULL;
ssize_t retval = 0;
.
. 
retval = recvfrom(server_socket, inputbuffer, maxLenght, 0, remote_addr, &server_addr_len);
```

SideNotes:

<sup>1. Define the variables in a way so that they do not need `cast`ing. Good practice.</sup>

<sup>2. check the return value of `recvfrom()` [or for that case, any library call] for success.</sup>

Comment: @iharob yeah difference is there. but why you say to _declare_, why not use _define_ term here? can you elaborate please? thank you.

Comment: Only `usigned int` make my compiler happy.

Comment: @iharob well, right, but usually, it's a better practice to initialize the variables. Combined, it makes a definition. :-)

Comment: @staigoun maybe, in your case, `socklen_t` is a typedef of `unsigned int`... why take chances?

Comment: @iharob: "*`socklen_t server_addr_len;`*" is a perfect valid definition (and an implicit declaration). Whereas "*`server_addr_len = someValue;`*" is not a definition but an initialisation!

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `server_addr_len` as `socklen_t`

```
socklen_t server_addr_len;
```

since the `recvfrom` function signature is

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
         struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but `gcc`compiler cannot compile this.

Comment: Do not cast a pointer to a pointer of a different type. This could lead to desaster in case the two types pointed to are of different size.